# Passing colons in query string in Apex

Tags: oracle, query-string, oracle-apex

I have a link in an apex report which takes the user to different page, and it passes some values to the new page. The button is set to a url because there are too many items being passed, but I don't think that would matter anyway:

```
f?p=&APP_ID.:27:&SESSION.::&DEBUG.::P27_1,P27_2,P27_3,P27_4,P27_5:0,#1#,#2#,#3#,#NULL#
```

The #1#, etc. are columns being passed. Everything seems to work correctly except that the data being passed often contains a colon (:), which messes up Apex's built in colon structure by cutting off anything in the new page's item that happens after the colon (including the colon itself) as well as messing up any fields after that.  For example: #2# has a colon in it, so P27_3, 4, and 5 will not be filled with values.

I've tried manually replacing the colon with a '%3a' (the url encoding for colon), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2383833.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to see if there was some built tool I was missing, but if there isn't I guess I will probably use this method.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to limit parameter values to nothing but numbers or simple alphabetic strings anyway. What kinds of values do you actually need to pass to the other page? Another idea is to directly set the target page item's value before you navigate to it.

Comment: Basically a lot of the columns are formatted text (think titles, bibliographic information, etc.), so they need to contain more than just alphanumeric characters unfortunately. It seems like if I could directly set the item it would solve the problem much more easily, but would that work across different pages? I'm guessing I would have to implement it somehow like [described here](http://patelkartik.blogspot.com/2010/08/set-or-get-apex-item-value.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UTL_URL.ESCAPE()` to escape URL special characters and `UTL_URL.UNESCAPE()` to un-escape them back.

You can also try `APEX_UTIL.URL_ENCODE()` but you need to use one or the other, i.e. either UTL or APEX_UTIL.